# Process.Start will not launch chrome

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I'm having trouble getting Process.Start to launch chrome. If chrome is set as the default browser - nothing is opened. I also have tried providing two argument ex:

```
    Process.Start("chrome",url)
    Process.Start("PathToChrome",url)
    Process.Start("chrome.exe",url)
```

None of those work either. It works fine when IE or Firefox are the default browser.
This same problem has been reproduced on two computers.

Comment: Not sure how the same code is supposed to work with IE and FF if you hardcode `chrome`.

Comment: Do you want to open an url in the default browser?

Comment: Sorry I meant Process.Start(url) works when IE or FF is the default browser. - and yes I want to open the URL in the default browser.

Comment: You mean Process.Start(url) does not work when Chrome is your default browser? For me every variant worked. Have you tried reinstalling Google Chrome?

Comment: I have no tried reinstalling - but this problem was duplicated on another computer.

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark, but: Since you tagged this question "windows installer", it occurs to me you may have been calling Process.Start() in a custom installer. If so, is the setup project property `InstallAllUsers` set to true? If so, set it to false and Process.Start(someUrl) should work correctly, even if Chrome is the default browser.